# How many sequences of 10 raindrops are there, where successive raindrops are the same size or larger than the previous?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The given question states that there are 3 types of raindrops. Small, medium and large respectively. Now, the total number of sequences in which 10 raindrops can fall is $3^{10}$. In solving this question, I understand the idea of using ordered integer partitions to find the number of sequences

$\binom{12}{10} = 66$ ways where we can think of this as an arrangement of the number of elements of each group of raindrop added together. This being $x_s + x_m + x_l = 10$ where $x_s$ represents the number of small raindrops to fall first, added to the number of medium raindrops to fall ($x_m$) afterwards and then finally adding the number of large raindrops ($x_l$) to fall last. Ultimately, the total number of each respective element can be thought of as a group of "1's" where there are ten "1's" in total, intermixed with two addition signs and we would find the total arrangement of these "1's" and "+'s".

However, is there another concise way of solving this problem?

Comment: Seems ok, a routine stars and bars approach for the numerator.

Answer (score 1):

If first drop is large then there is only one way to do this.

If first drop is medium then there are $g(n-1)$ days where $g$ counts only sequences with medium or large

If first drop is small then we can do this in as many ways as with $n-1$ drops.

And so we can write a recurrence relation.

$f(n) = 1+ g(n-1) + f(n-1)$

$$g(n-1) = 1 + g(n-2)$$
$$g(n-2) = 1 + g(n-2)$$
$$\vdots$$
$$g(1) = 2$$

Adding we get $g(n-1) = n$

$$f(n) = 1 + n + f(n-1) $$
$$f(n-1) = 1 + n-1 + f(n-2)$$
$$\vdots$$
$$ f(1) = 1 + 1 + 1$$

Adding we get $f(n) = n + \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + 1 = \frac{n^2 + 3n + 2}{2} = \binom{n+2}{2}$

The stars and bars approach is likely easier. Think of it as $n$ identical drops placed in $3$ bins where bins can be empty. Then label the bins S,M,L from left to right.

Comment: I think you should add how to reach $\binom{n+2}{2}$ to your answer